# C++ return by reference RapidJSON

Tags: c++

In this snippet I need to return `Value&` but obviously I get a lot of errors.

```
class MyClass
{

public:
    Value& getResult(char* response);
};

Value& MyClass::getResult(char* response)
{
    Document d;
    d.Parse(response);
    printf("Has parse errors: %s\r\n", d.HasParseError() ? "true" : "false");

    Value& results = d[results];

    return results;
}
```

Would be nice if you can give some insights as well. I have never used C in this way so, this new area for me.

Comment: Perhaps sharing the errors would help? `Value& results = d[results];` makes no sense at all...

Comment: You are returning a local reference. This is an UB. You can return a copy of it or make `d` persistent

Comment: You cannot return reference to local variables.

Comment: *" I have never used C in this way"* - you should not use C++ in this way too.

Comment: @John3136 Its just example code from: http://rapidjson.org/

Comment: @DigitalHuman How are we supposed to know what is the real code with errors and what is the example code?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

The `Document` is a local variable, and [presumably] the result of `d[results]` is a local variable.

Then you're trying to bind it to a reference and return that reference. Even if this were legal, it would be a dangling reference, referring to nothing.

Instead, use the principles of RAII and just return a `Value`.